# Check if predictive text is enabled

Tags: ios, ios8

I would like to know if there is any way to check wether predictive text (the grey boxes above the keyboard) are enabled.

I need this to scoll a view a few pixel more to the top when the textfield gets its focus. I get the size of the keyboard with: `CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use end frame to get the last position the keyboard will end up. So in your `keyboardWillShow:` notification callback get the keyboard end frame.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.object;
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    // Use keyboardEndFrame
}
```

This even works when user resizes the predictive text view (shrink/expand) and also works if you have an input accessory view.

### Edit

The real answer to the title of this question is different. As of now, there is no obvious way to find out if the predictive text is enabled. So I came up a solution which checks keyboard frame with different autocorrection types.

#### ZSTKeyboardChecker.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ZSTKeyboardChecker : NSObject

- (BOOL)isPredictiveTextEnabledForTextField:(UITextField *)textField;

@end
```

#### ZSTKeyboardChecker.m

```
@interface ZSTKeyboardChecker ()

@property (assign, nonatomic) CGRect keyboardEndFrame;

@end

@implementation ZSTKeyboardChecker

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isPredictiveTextEnabledForTextField:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.autocorrectionType == UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo) {
        return NO;
    }

    BOOL isFirstResponder = [textField isFirstResponder];
    BOOL autoCorrectionType = [textField autocorrectionType];

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    // Get the frame with possibly including predictive text
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    CGRect predictiveKeyboardEndFrame = self.keyboardEndFrame;
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    // Get the keyboard frame without predictive text
    textField.autocorrectionType = UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo;
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    CGRect defaultKeyboardEndFrame = self.keyboardEndFrame;
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    // Restore state
    textField.autocorrectionType = autoCorrectionType;
    if (isFirstResponder) {
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    BOOL isPredictiveTextEnabled = !CGPointEqualToPoint(predictiveKeyboardEndFrame.origin, defaultKeyboardEndFrame.origin);
    return isPredictiveTextEnabled;
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.object;
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
    [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    self.keyboardEndFrame = keyboardEndFrame;
}

@end
```

#### Usage (You may want to check it only once)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    ZSTKeyboardChecker *keyboardChecker = [[ZSTKeyboardChecker alloc] init];
    BOOL isPredictiveTextEnabled = [keyboardChecker isPredictiveTextEnabledForTextField:self.textField];

    NSLog(@"Enabled: %d", isPredictiveTextEnabled);
}
```

Comment: Both keys `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` give me the same values in `keyboardWillShow`. Both give me a value in height of 253.0.

I tried: `[[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height`

Comment: Actually both height and origin of the keyboard should change when you enable/disable suggestions. What happens when you swipe down the predictive text bar? Is not `keyboardEndFrame` changes?

Comment: Sure you are absolutely right. The height will not change. Awesome answer, thanks. I just had to change my calculation to move the view.

Still disappointed why no actual keyboard (keyboard + predictive text) height is provided by cocoa.

Comment: I found out that when swiping down the predictive text bar, origin remains the same and height (obviously) changes, but remains higher than "default" size... I ended up checking for heights too, having this in mind.